# Configure YAPF with PEP8 styling to ignore whitespace around equals operator

Tags: python, pep8, yapf

I'm using YAPF with the PEP8 style, and I'm trying to ignore whenever there's whitespace around the equals '=' operator, for example:

```
environment: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = None
```

Is formatted to:

```
environment: Optional[Dict[str, str]]=None
```

There isn't a YAPF knob (https://github.com/google/yapf#knobs) which allows me to change this configuration.

Is there a way to make YAPF use some custom PEP8 configuration, or change this setting?

Answer (score 0):

add the following lines to .pyproject.toml

```
[yapf]
style = pep8
spaces_around_eq = no
```

Comment: This errors for me and says 'Unknown style option "SPACES_AROUND_EQ"
Do you have a documentation link showing its usage?